# How to setup Rails System Test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, installation, selenium-chromedriver, snap

I am currently trying to set up some system testing for my rails web application (using Rails version 7.0.3.1)

When running rails test:system to run a single system test I had written, I am getting the below setup-related error

```
Command '/usr/bin/chromium-browser' requires the chromium snap to be installed.
Please install it with:

snap install chromium

.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/webdrivers-5.0.0/lib/webdrivers/system.rb:190:in `call': Failed to make system call: ["/usr/bin/chromium-browser", "--product-version"] (RuntimeError)
```

And then, when I try to run

`snap install chromium`

as suggested by the error I am getting back, I then run into the following error

```
error: cannot communicate with server: Post http://localhost/v2/snaps/chromium: dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: no such file or directory
```

I am lost as to how to move forward with this issue, which is preventing me from being able to run any system tests. There also seem to not be too many related issues online currently that applied to this case. Any help/ suggestions on where to look to further troubleshoot this error would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You'd probably need to enable the snap service, see here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1258137/cannot-communicate-with-server-post-http-localhost-v2-apps-dial-unix-run-sn

Answer (score 1):

Try to install it from the Google, depends on your ubuntu versions:

```
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
apt install ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```